# Does calling a c function via ctypes in python release the GIL during execution of the C code

Tags: python, ctypes, gil, python-cffi

I want to call some c function from python to be able to improve performance of my code. But I cannot find online whether when I call a C function using the ctypes libraries the GIL is released. As a simple example:

```
from ctypes import *
fun = cdll.LoadLibrary("libc.so.6")
fun.sleep.argtypes = [c_uint]
fun.sleep(c_uint(5))
```

Is the GIL released during the call to `fun.sleep`?

Comment: Note you don't have to wrap arguments.  `ctypes` knows the argument types via `.argtypes`, so `fun.sleep(5)` works fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [[Python.Docs]: ctypes.CFUNCTYPE(restype, *argtypes, use_errno=False, use_last_error=False)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CFUNCTYPE) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The returned function prototype creates functions that use the standard C calling convention. The function **will release the GIL during the call**.

Also (in order to link **FUNCTYPE* and **DLL*), [[Python.Docs]: class ctypes.PyDLL(name, mode=DEFAULT_MODE, handle=None)](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.PyDLL) (**emphasis** still mine):

> Instances of this class behave like [CDLL](https://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CDLL) instances, **except that the Python GIL is *not* released during the function call**

Therefore, the answer to your question is: **YES**.

As a side note, if *fun.sleep* is called many times (like in a loop or something), there's time "lost" in marshalling data between *Python* and *C* for every call, and in that case you might want to consider writing the whole loop in *C*.

Comment: Very clear, thanks! Still quite unexpected that this is not documented with CDLL instead.

Comment: You're welcome! Well, *CDLL* and *CFUNCTYPE* are coupled.

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if this were started directly in the CLL documentation, but the following article provides a convincing test : http://caswenson.com/2009_06_13_bypassing_the_python_gil_with_ctypes.html

**Edit:** I spoke too soon: the CFUNCTYPE documentation is pretty explicit about releasing the GIL: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.CFUNCTYPE